Is there an analog of swagger ui for gRPC API?
Is there an analog of Swagger UI, that can visualise gRPC API (.proto files) to HTML, like Swagger UI for OpenAPI .json or .yaml documents?

One tool is Buf Schema Registry

Hello @DazWilkin unfortunately I have got 403 on your link.

I found protoc-gen-doc. To generate html from .proto files, we can run the following command:
protoc --doc_out=./doc --doc_opt=html,index.html proto/*.proto

Example of output result
